# There is no row at position 0 error TableAdapter

Tags: vb.net, dataset, tableadapter

I get this error every time I try to get the first column value of each row.

```
Dim modAdapter As New StudentSystemDBDataSetTableAdapters.modulesTableAdapter
Dim modDataset As New StudentSystemDBDataSet

If modAdapter.ModulesCountRow() <> 0 Then
    For x As Integer = 0 To modAdapter.ModulesCountRow()
        Dim column As String = modDataset.modules.Rows(x)(0).ToString
        MsgBox(column)
    Next
End If`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexes are zero based. So the first row is at `modDataset.modules.Rows(0)` and the last at `modDataset.modules.Rows(modAdapter.ModulesCountRow() - 1)`.

So you have to subtract 1:

```
For x As Integer = 0 To modAdapter.ModulesCountRow() - 1
    Dim column As String = modDataset.modules.Rows(x)(0).ToString
    MsgBox(column)
Next
```

**Edit**: you can also use the `DataTable.Rows.Count` property if it's already filled. Then you don't need to get the row-count from database with the dataadapter:

```
For x As Integer = 0 To modDataset.modules.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim column As String = modDataset.modules.Rows(x)(0).ToString
    MsgBox(column)
Next
```

Comment: Hello I just tried that im still getting the same error

Comment: @Inaloz_H: use the (hopefully already filled) `DataTable` instead. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The error is eliminated but now the msgbox is not displaying.  Ive got 5 rows in the table. The for loop skips

Comment: @Inaloz_H: yes, because the rows are only in your database table and not in the (in-memory) dataset/datatable. You have to use the DataAdapter  to fill the `DataTable` first (`modAdapter.Fill(modDataset.modules)`).

Comment: Oohhh!! Thanks a lot @Tim Schmelter , youre  my hero.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your dataset (modules) has rows:

```
If modDataset.modules.Rows.Count > 0 AndAlso modAdapter.ModulesCountRow() <> 0 Then
            For x As Integer = 0 To modAdapter.ModulesCountRow()
                Dim column As String = modDataset.modules.Rows(x)(0).ToString
                MsgBox(column)
            Next
        End If
```

Comment: Hello. Modules is the name of my dataset im trying to access. That wont work.